# Javascript Create Clickable Text

Tags: javascript, css, html

**EDIT 2**  - I decided to create a simple example with jsfiddle.

> http://jsfiddle.net/VqA9g/61/

As you can see, I am trying to reference the new div.

**EDIT** - d/t negative votes and unclear question

I have a linked-list like so:

```
var struct_list = function () {
    this.id = 0;
    this.name = 0;
    this._head = null;
};
struct_list.prototype = {

// .. adding code , delete code ...

list_contents: function () {
    var current = this._head;
    while ( current != null ) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "white";
        div.style.color = "black";
        div.style.top = "0px";
        div.style.left = "0px";
        div.style.margin = "400px 1000px auto"; 
        div.style.cursor = "pointer";
        div.innerHTML = current.name;
        div.onclick = function ( v ) { var d = document.getElementById('div'); alert(d)};
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        current = current.next;
    }
    return null;
},};
```

I want to be able to display this linked list, and each item displayed be able to interact with an "onclick".

Example:

`struct_list.add ( 0 , "Zero" );`
`struct_list.add ( 1 , "One" );`

struct_list.list_contents();

```
_________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                        |
| <clickable> "Zero" that does a function(id) that passes over its ID(0) |
|________________________________________________________________________|
|                                                                        |
| <clickable> "One" <same as above>                                      |
|________________________________________________________________________|
```

**Sorry** if I was unclear.  Will reedit if still unclear.  My apologies.

---

I have a linked-list struct that I hold data in (it changes data frequently) and I have a setInterval to refresh it.  My question is how can I list the struct's contents while still being able to click the exposed content,  I have it set up right now that each content in the linked-list contains an id. Also , how can I make sure that overflow is automatic for the y axis?  I am guessing I have to place it into a div that has that enabled.

But my real question is how to expose the linked-lists elements while also being able to interact with them via an onclick.

I also do not want to use anything other than pure javascript.

Example (in my mind) would maybe be something like:

```
<div id="PopUp">
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            if ( struct_qued_list ) {
                struct_qued_list = false;
                main.struct_list.list_contents(); // the linked list
            }
        }, 100);
    </script>
</div>


list_contents: function () {
    var current = this._head;
    while ( current != null ) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "white";
        div.style.color = "black";
        div.style.top = "0px";
        div.style.left = "0px";
        div.style.margin = "400px 1000px auto"; 
        div.style.cursor = "pointer";
        div.innerHTML = current.name;
        div.onclick = function ( v ) { var d = document.getElementById('div'); alert(d)};
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        current = current.next;
    }
    return null;
},
```

Any help or logical way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want to achieve.. Why not start by setting up an example of what you have in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a scope problem, in your [Edit 2 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqA9g/61/), the alert gives undefined because your `i` got the value `2` in order to leave the loop.

Here is a possible solution : [Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/VqA9g/64/)

```js
!function(){
    var index = i; // Make it independant of i
    div.onclick = function () { alert(list[index]); };
}();
```

---

You could also use attributes to store any value, and using `this` in the function to retrieve it.

---

Or export the whole process to another function to obtain something like this :

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++ ) {
    doSomething(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Thats exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score -1):

When you add new content to the DOM JavaScript sometimes has a hard time picking that up. You may need to use a DOM mutation event (like [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent)) to add the event listeners to your text nodes.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(){

     document.getElementById('thing').addEventListener('click', function(){
         alert('yey!');
     });

 });
```

you may need to name your functions so you can remove them as well, if nodes are going to be inserted without removing all the old ones. Yes this is pure javascript.

**EDIT**: for your overflow issue, you could assign a class to each node as you insert it and style the class via CSS

```
 .classname {
     overflow: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Black_Stormy, thank you for your time and response, I have edited my original post.  My apologies.